# Firebase getPhotoUrl retrieves a low quality image

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase to sign in with facebook, G+ and twitter, everything is alright until I need to get the user profile picture, I'm using the getPhotoURl method and it retrieves me an image in very low quality.

```
Glide.with(this).load(currentUser.getPhotoUrl() != null ? currentUser.getPhotoUrl().toString() : "").into(ivDisplayPhoto);
```

Is there a way using Firebase to get the profile picture in a better quality?

Answer (score 1):

The photos from the authentication tool are only intended to be used as thumbnails and for small display. Without adding other SDKs to your project this may not be possible.

If the image quality is important to you it may be easiest to ask the user to upload a profile photo to your app directly.

Otherwise, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started